# Pi Pico w website, not working, loads up % on site instead of number

Tags: pi-pico

Pi Pico w website, not working, loads up % on site instead of number
My code does not work, I based it of an example

here is how it looks:

> [image: Image of website]

```
    # Based on sample code provided here :
# https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/how-to-run-a-webserver-on-raspberry-pi-pico-w/

print("Runnng code")

#import stuff
import network
import socket
import time
import urequests

#led
from machine import Pin
led = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
led_on = 0
led_off = 1
led_change = 0

ConnectCount = 0

from secret import WifiSSID
from secret import WifiPassword

ssid = WifiSSID
password = WifiPassword

#Default hosted website text
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        h1 {text-align: center;}
        p {text-align: center;}
        div {text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <title>:)</title> </head>
    <body> <h1>Pico W Hosted Website</h1>
    
        <p>%s</p>
        <br>
        <p>%%</p>
        
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">This is a link</a>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <a href="http://192.168.68.69/light/on">Turn on led</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://192.168.68.69/light/off">Turn off led</a>
    </body>
</html>
"""

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)

connectCount = 0.5


max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    print('waiting for connection...')
    time.sleep(1)

if wlan.status() != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
else:
    print('connected')
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print( 'ip = ' + status[0] )

addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(addr)
s.listen(1)

# Get current time
r = urequests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip')
result = str(r.content)
startTime = result[int(result.find("datetime")) + 11:30 + result.find("datetime")]


print('Start Time', startTime)
print('listening on', addr)

# Listen for connections
while True:
    try:
        cl, addr = s.accept()
        clientIP = addr[0]
        
        r = urequests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip')
        result = str(r.content)
        reachTime = result[int(result.find("datetime")) + 11:30 + result.find("datetime")]
        
        print(reachTime, 'client connected from', clientIP)
        request = cl.recv(1024)
        request = str(request)
        ConnectCount += 0.5 #0.5 instead of 1 bc 2x log
        CountText = "This site has been accessed " + str(ConnectCount) + " times since " + startTime
        
        #Led has been changed x times since y
        LedChangeText = "Led has been changed " + str(led_change) + " times since  " + startTime


        response = html % CountText
        response2 = html % LedChangeText

        cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        cl.send(response)
        cl.close()
        
        cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        cl.send(response2)
        cl.close()
        
        request = str(request)
        led_on = request.find('/light/on')
        led_off = request.find('/light/off')
        print( 'led on = ' + str(led_on))
        print( 'led off = ' + str(led_off))

        if led_on == 6:
            print("led on")
            led.value(1)
            led_change += 1
            stateis = "LED is ON"

        if led_off == 6:
            print("led off")
            led.value(0)
            led_change += 1
            stateis = "LED is OFF"

    except OSError as e:
        cl.close()
        print('connection closed')
```

LOG:

```
MicroPython v1.19.1 on 2022-08-26; Raspberry Pi Pico W with RP2040

Type "help()" for more information.
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Runnng code
secret running
waiting for connection...
waiting for connection...
waiting for connection...
waiting for connection...
connected
ip = 192.168.68.69
Start Time 2022-08-30T17:38:58
listening on ('0.0.0.0', 80)
2022-08-30T17:39:10 client connected from 192.168.68.72
connection closed
2022-08-30T17:39:13 client connected from 192.168.68.72
connection closed
2022-08-30T17:39:16 client connected from 192.168.68.72
connection closed
enter code here
```

My main question is why is only "%" display and not the string/number (which represents the amount of times that the LED has been changed)?

Comment: please add a focused question to your post

Comment: what does this mean? ... `loads up % on site instead of number`

Comment: @jsotola it means it loads up the character "%" instead of the string and number i want there on the website

Comment: let me rephrase the question ... what number should be there?

Comment: the amount of times that the led has been changed

Comment: Solved this problem, my dad helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was the dubble

```
cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
    cl.send(response2)
    cl.close()
```

and

```
response2 = html % LedChangeText
```

small problem with Spelling too at

```
<p>%s</p>
<br>
<p>%%</p> #here it should be %s
```

it should be "%s" not "%%"

the correct and updated code (if you want to use it, change ip in line 58 and 60) is:

```
    # Based on sample code provided here :
# https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/how-to-run-a-webserver-on-raspberry-pi-pico-w/

print("Runnng code")

#import stuff
import network
import socket
import time
import urequests

#led
from machine import Pin
led = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
led_on = 0
led_off = 1
led_change = 0

ConnectCount = 0.5

led.value(1)
time.sleep(1)
led.value(0)
time.sleep(1)
led.value(1)
time.sleep(1)
led.value(0)
time.sleep(1)

from secret import WifiSSID
from secret import WifiPassword

ssid = WifiSSID
password = WifiPassword

#Default hosted website text
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        h1 {text-align: center;}
        p {text-align: center;}
        div {text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <title>:)</title> </head>
    <body> <h1>Pico W Hosted Website</h1>
    
        <p>%s</p>
        <br>
        <p>%s</p>
        
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">This is a link</a>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <a href="http://192.168.68.69/light/on">Turn on led</a>
        <br>
        <a href="http://192.168.68.69/light/off">Turn off led</a>
    </body>
</html>
"""

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)

connectCount = 0.5


max_wait = 10
while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
        break
    max_wait -= 1
    print('waiting for connection...')
    time.sleep(1)

if wlan.status() != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
else:
    print('connected')
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print( 'ip = ' + status[0] )

addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(addr)
s.listen(1)

# Get current time
r = urequests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip')
result = str(r.content)
startTime = result[int(result.find("datetime")) + 11:30 + result.find("datetime")]


print('Start Time', startTime)
print('listening on', addr)

# Listen for connections
while True:
    try:
        cl, addr = s.accept()
        clientIP = addr[0]
        
        r = urequests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip')
        result = str(r.content)
        reachTime = result[int(result.find("datetime")) + 11:30 + result.find("datetime")]
        
        print(reachTime, 'client connected from', clientIP)
        request = cl.recv(1024)
        request = str(request)
        ConnectCount += 0.5 #0.5 instead of 1 bc 2x log
        CountText = "This site has been accessed " + str(ConnectCount) + " times since " + startTime
        
        #Led has been changed x times since y
        LedChangeText = "Led has been changed " + str(led_change) + " times since  " + startTime


        response = html % (CountText, LedChangeText)

        cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        cl.send(response)
        cl.close()
        
        request = str(request)
        led_on = request.find('/light/on')
        led_off = request.find('/light/off')
        print( 'led on = ' + str(led_on))
        print( 'led off = ' + str(led_off))

        if led_on == 6:
            print("led on")
            led.value(1)
            led_change += 1
            stateis = "LED is ON"

        if led_off == 6:
            print("led off")
            led.value(0)
            led_change += 1
            stateis = "LED is OFF"

    except OSError as e:
        cl.close()
        print('connection closed')
```